# JQ: How to multiply values that are recognised as strings?

Tags: json, bash, jq, multiplication, string-substitution

I am trying to get some trade information from an exchange websocket.
Both values .p and .q are enclosed between double quotes in the JSON I get from the socket.

When I try to multiply two values, it says I am trying to multiply two strings. So I pass those strings though the tonumber filter and the error message changes a bit, but can't get it to work really.

JSON:

```
{"e":"aggTrade","E":1562109562958,"s":"BTCUSDT","a":134343336,"p":"10796.60000000","q":"0.00139000","f":147532295,"l":147532295,"T":1562109562951,"m":false,"M":true}
```

The commands below are followed by their outputs:

```
... | jq  '"\(.p*.q)"'
    jq: error (at <stdin>:1): string ("10796.6000...) and string ("0.00139000") cannot be multiplied
```

Then:

```
... | jq  '"\(.p|tonumber*.q|tonumber)"'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "q"
```

```
... | jq  '"\("\(.p|tonumber)"*"\(.q|tonumber)")"'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): string ("10796.6") and string ("0.00139") cannot be multiplied
```

The closest I get is with the code below, but it  outputs many pages of results and I only expect one result...

```
... | jq  '.q as $qtty | "\(.p|tonumber*$qtty|tonumber)"'
```

Or:

```
... | jq  '.q as $qtty | "\(.p|tonumber*"\($qtty|tonumber)")"'
```

It outputs too many numbers!

Even with the -r option, it does not work.
I would expect just the raw result of multiplication to appear, like so:

```
15.0072740
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep it simple,

```
jq -r '(.p | tonumber)*(.q | tonumber)'
```