# How do I multiply two json with jq?

Tags: jq

Got `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`

want it be `{"a": 1, "b": 6, "c": 3}`

but if I `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} * {"b": 3}` it ends up `{"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 3}`.

How do I make it happen with jq?

Comment: are you sure the numbers are rly numbers or strings? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861281/jq-how-to-multiply-values-that-are-recognised-as-strings

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiply the .b value in an object by 3, you could write:

```
.b *= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a multiplication operation on JSON objects, consider:

```
def multiply(o):
  reduce (o|keys_unsorted[]) as $k (.; .[$k] *= o[$k]);
```

Using your example:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} | multiply({"b":3})
```

yields:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 6,
  "c": 3
}
```